# Unable to connect to my ubuntu server by using its ip address

Tags: networking, server

After establish my ubuntu server 20.04.3 server I have tried to restart its network by using:
`systemctl restart systemd-networkd`
Then I used:
`ip addr` in order to get my ip address.
Then I tried to connect to this ip address but it says: This site can’t be reached

Do you have an idea what the problem might be?
I've tried to search for the solution without a success.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Which IP address were you trying to connect to? I hope it wasn’t `127.0.0.1` 

Comment: probably `192.168.0.1`

Comment: Even assuming you used the correct IP what exactly were you expecting? Did you configured network shares? SSH?...

Comment: Could you edit your answer and post the result of your commands?  Could you also be more specific about how exactly you tried to connect?

Comment: I have used the ip address as @Liso mentioned, (not the localhost and not the 0.1 ending). My server was configured as ssh. So after I did a reset to the network I tried to connect to it through the browser by using the relevant ip address of the server without success

Comment: Let’s back up a bit, because there’s a lack of information here. Does the server have Apache or nginx installed to handle web requests? Is `ufw` configured correctly? Why did you need to restart the network? What were you editing that required such a thing? 

Comment: I installed apache2 on my server.  
I connected to the server by using ```ssh username@{server_ip_address}```.
Then I searched for its ip address by using ```ip a``` and tried to connect to it via my firefox browser.
For some reason it can't connect to my server. I did exactly what it done in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNNahW0gRZQ

Comment: Just did it again and now it works fine, god knows why hehe
thank you very much guys!